# Trying to get a subset of data using ECMAScript Regular Expression where one string doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, regex

So I find this really hard to explain what im doing, but its easy to show in an example.
I have these 2 strings and I need a regular expression that will only return a value for one of them

```
Ref Numbers: RCPT:02972, VLBL#:7158461 $930.38
2012-10- 01 5558461 abagaa
```

I need the 5558461 but not the 7158461, so basically a 7 digit number. I was trying to do this where Ref Numbers exists do not return anything, but if it doesn't then return the 7 digit number.

I've tried many different things but I just cannot get what I need. does anyone out there have an idea what needs to be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative lookahead assertion like below,

```
^(?!.*Ref).*\b(\d{7})\b
```

Use the above regex and get the number you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iB9oP9/6)

```
> var s = "Ref Numbers: RCPT:02972, VLBL#:7158461 $930.38\n2012-10- 01 5558461 abagaa"
> console.log(/^(?!.*Ref).*\b(\d{7})\b/m.exec(s)[1]);
5558461
```

Negative lookahead `(?!.*Ref)` at the first asserts that the line where the match  going to occur won't have the string like `Ref`